# ostream to ostringstream(downcasting) in C++ with Qt & MVC

Tags: c++, qt, stream, downcast

I need to convert a ostream's object in a ostringstream's object.
This is the code:

```
//gerarchia_view.h
class bagaglio_view{
private:
    std::ostream& os;
    std::string data;
public:
    bagaglio_view();
    std::string print_bagaglio(const bagaglio &b) const;
};

//gerarchia_view.cpp
bagaglio_view::bagaglio_view():data(" "),os(std::cout){
}

std::string bagaglio_view::print_bagaglio(const bagaglio& b) const{
    os<<b; // operator << is overloaded
    std::ostringstream* oss=static_cast<std::ostringstream*>(&os);
    return oss->str(); // down-cast, segm fault
}
```

I need the function

```
std::string bagaglio_view::print_bagaglio(const bagaglio& b) const;
```

return the string that is in std::ostream os.
How can I solve that? I tried dynamic_cast and using a std::ostringstream in substution of std::ostream, but operator<< doesn't work.

Comment: Does your `std::ostream&` actually refer to a `std::ostringstream` or something else?

Comment: no but it's construct in                                                                                    bagaglio_view::bagaglio_view()

Comment: That constructor doesn't attach your `std::ostream&` to a `std::ostringstream` it attaches it to ` std::cout` which is **not** a `std::ostringstream`. If you cast it to the wrong type its undefined behavior, it breaks.

Comment: Ok. So, what I use in substitution of std::cout ?

Comment: You say you want to *"return the string that is in std::ostream os"* but the problem is that `std::ostream` objects don't usually contain strings. For example `std::ofstream` sends its output to the hard disk. `std::cout` sends its output to the console. They do not keep internal string copies of everything they output. It is only `std::ostringstream` that does that. **So what are you trying to achieve?** Maybe we can find another way to do it?